# Android Method ... not mocked

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

Hi i am trying to run a instrumental test and i keep getting this error.

i tried adding the below test options:

```
testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
```

But i now get an error saying Gradle DSL method not found testOptions().

i am using the following gradle plugin:

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

Here is my simple testcase

```
public class ExampleUnitTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
        Context context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
        assertNotNull(context);
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full "build.gradle" file?  The error message you reference (...not mocked) is the message you usually get when you run an instrumentation test as a regular junit test.  How are you running the test (ie from menu or using a launch configuration?